# Deserializing schema.org microdata from HTML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, schema.org, microdata

I am looking for a way to deserialize a set of offline HTML pages that have schema.org microdata embedded. How could I do this in C#? I have found [Bam.Net.Schema.Org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Bam.Net.Schema.Org/) but there is almost no code that teaches me how to use it.

I have found several "parsers" for node.js but they are imperfect and not something I could use from C# - at least not in way I would prefer ([semantic-schema-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/semantic-schema-parser) and [node-microdata-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-microdata-scraper)).

Suggestions are welcome. Should I simply create my own?

Answer (score 0):

You can use HtmlAgilityPack to parse the html and than query the DOM for schema.org values.